# Help writing a test class for a trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

Can anybody help me please to finish this test class, I am new in testing class and I spent the whole day trying to get coverage for this trigger, so far I get 33% and looks like the only part of the code that is getting coverage is the AggregateResult.

Here is the trigger:

```
Trigger OSOCount on Purchase_Order__c (before update) {
    for(AggregateResult result : [
            SELECT PO_Lookback__c, SUM(Total_Qty_to_Ship__c)
            FROM Outbound_Sales_Order__c
            WHERE PO_Lookback__c IN :Trigger.new
            GROUP BY PO_Lookback__c
            ]){
        Purchase_Order__c prod = Trigger.newMap.get((string)result.get('PO_Lookback__c'));
        prod.OSO_Count__c= (double)result.get('expr0');
    }
}
```

here is the testing class I am working on, I will appreciate any help

```
@istest
public class Test_OSOCount 
{ 
    private static testmethod void TestOSOCount ()
    {
        Account account1 = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1');
        insert account1;


        Purchase_Order__c  aa = new Purchase_Order__c (Account__c = account1.id);
        insert aa;
        aa.OSO_Count__c=5;
        update aa;

        test.StartTest();
        update aa;
        test.StopTest();
        System.assertEquals(5,aa.OSO_Count__c);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that while you do insert a `Purchase_Order__c` you never update it and the trigger is a "before update" trigger.

**PS** OK you just changed the test code. My answer relates to version 2 of the question.

**PPS** The test needs to wire up the objects and then update the `Purchase_Order__c` (assuming the trigger does what is required):

```
@istest
public class Test_OSOCount { 
    private Static testmethod void TestOSOCount () {

        Account a = new Account(Name = 'Test Account1');
        insert a;

        Purchase_Order__c po = new Purchase_Order__c(Account__c = a.id);
        insert po

        insert new Outbound_Sales_Order__c[] {
                new Outbound_Sales_Order__c(PO_Lookback__c = po.Id, Total_Qty_to_Ship__c = 4),
                new Outbound_Sales_Order__c(PO_Lookback__c = po.Id, Total_Qty_to_Ship__c = 9)
                };

        update po;
        System.assertEquals(4 + 9, [
                select OSO_Count__c
                from Purchase_Order__c
                where Id = :po.Id
                ].OSO_Count__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Keith, so what is the best approach in this case?

Comment: @Carlos I've added the sort of test code I would write toe the answer.

Comment: Keith, thank you so much.. that is very clean and easy to follow. I just find my self so lost doing this test classes for triggers, would you recommend me some resources that will help me to understand this.

Comment: @Carlos All I can suggest is that you google the keywords and read everything that comes up: I don't know of any particularly good articles on the subject. That is a pity as e.g. for Java JUnit there are whole books on testing patterns. Triggers require setup, appropriate changes and requerying to check the results; generally test examples are short on structure such as the use of builder or fixture classes.